# PHP array ordering

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I was wondering how I could sort this array, when I use asort right now it does

14
17
16
15.

How would I go to have

14
15
16
17

```
  array(4) { 
        [15]=>  array(9) { 
         [2025]=>  string(80) "20:25 à 21:15 Spectacle / L'histoire d'un coeur / Auditorium, É.S.P. De La Salle" 
         [2135]=>  string(71) "21:35 à 22:25 Spectacle / Transfugue 2 / Auditorium, É.S.P. De La Salle" 
         [1430]=>  string(64) "14:30 à 15:30 Mise en lecture/Théâtre la Catapulte / De La Salle" 
         [110]=>  string(44) "11:00 à 13:00 Inscription / Pavillon Tabaret" 
         [1330]=>  string(49) "13:30 à 14:30 CÉRÉMONIE D'OUVERTURE / De La Salle" 
         [1550]=>  string(61) "15:50 à 16:40 Spectacle/Université Laurentienne / De La Salle" 
         [170]=>  string(57) "17:00 à 17:50 Spectacle/Université d'Ottawa / De La Salle" 
         [1750]=>  string(45) "17:50 à 19:00 REPAS DE L'AMITIÉ / De La Salle" 
         [1915]=>  string(76) "19:15 à 20:05 Spectacle / Attendre la pluie / Auditorium, É.S.P. De La Salle" } 
        [16]=>  array(8) { 
         [1845]=>  string(81) "18:45 à 19:35 Spectacle / Mimes d'horreur / Salle Académique, Université d'Ottawa" 
         [1955]=>  string(73) "19:55 à 20:45 Spectacle / Déroute / Salle Académique, Université d'Ottawa" 
         [8]=>  string(45) "08:30 à 11:30 Atelier / ABC du jeu dramatique" 
         [13]=>  string(41) "13:00 à 16:00 Atelier / Théâtre physique" 
         [1130]=>  string(28) "11:30 à 13:00 DÎNER LIBRE / " 
         [1620]=>  string(29) "16:20 à 18:20 SOUPER LIBRE / " 
         [220]=>  string(58) "22:00 à 23:30 BAL MASQUÉ / l'Agora du centre universitaire" 
         [210]=>  string(47) "21:00 à 22:00 Rétroaction / Université d'Ottawa" } 
        [17]=>  array(4) { 
         [950]=>  string(79) "09:50 à 10:40 Spectacle / Raison d'être / Salle Académique, Université d'Ottawa" 
         [110]=>  string(76) "11:00 à 11:50 Spectacle / Potionnée / Salle Académique, Université d'Ottawa" 
         [120]=>  string(28) "12:00 à 13:00 DÎNER LIBRE / " 
         [1330]=>  string(48) "13:30 à 14:30 CÉRÉMONIE DE CLÔTURE / De La Salle" } 
        [14]=>  array(1) { 
         [150]=>  string(49) "15:00 à 16:30 Préparation technique / De La Salle" } }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want [ksort()](http://www.php.net/ksort), which will sort the array by key instead of value.

Comment: Good catch, I would have suggested the same :)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the sort by key function:

```
ksort()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check out http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php. There are some examples there of how how to implement the sort the way you want. Also if its sorted but you want the reverse order use array_reverse().

Comment: how about using the reverse of `ksort` or `sort` instead of `array_reserve`? like `krsort` or `rsort` respectively